# Create Android Startup Service with Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to create an android background service that is automatically started after the boot is completed from within a Cordova plugin?

In my concrete example, I need to start a service that always listens for Bluetooth events (even if the actual application is not started).

In theory, this simply requires a Broadcast Receiver that listens for the BOOT_COMPLETED event which then starts a Broadcast Receiver that listens for the Bluetooth events.

However, since I need to work with a Cordova application, I do not have access to the AndroidManifest.xml file which is required for my solution above.

My question is: Is there a way to access the AndroidManifest.xml file from Cordova or is there any other way that I have not thought of that would give me the same result?

Regards,
Lehks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for the plugin.xml file: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file

You can have a section called `<config-file>` which can add to the AndroidManifest.xml. For example (from the docs):

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
    <activity android:name="com.foo.Foo" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</config-file>
```

Simply add your broadcast receiver this way.